# Hibernate classcast exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, classcastexception

Hi

Below is my query.

```
ProgramAccess access = null;
access =  (ProgramAccess)entityManager.
    createQuery("update ProgramAccess p set p.isDeleted = 1 where p.id in (:progId)")
    .setParameter("progId", idStrArray).getResultList();
```

I am getting below exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.sony.spe.b2b.entity.ProgramAccess
```

Though I am casting it, why it is giving exception?

Comment: an update statement will not fetch any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mixing between `update` and `select` statements. An update statement wont fetch any object. Therefore, usuing `Query#getResultList` is wrong. `Query#executeUpdate` will be better to use.

From the docs.

> getResultList
>
> java.util.List getResultList() Execute a SELECT query and return the
>   query results as an untyped List. Returns: a list of the results

Then, proper syntax should be like below statement, if an update will be performed.

```
Query query = entityManager.
    createQuery("delete from user_tags where tag_id = :tagId and user_id = :userId");
        query.setParameter("progId", idStrArray);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

It is also possible to perform select statement using sql and entities. `Query#setResultTransformer` can be used for entity mapping. It is important to be careful about selected fields and entity mappings match.

```
Query query =  (ProgramAccess)entityManager.
    createQuery("Proper select statement which matches with entity mapping.").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ProgramAccess.class));
query.setParameter("progId", idStrArray);
List<ProgramAccess> list = query.list();
```

**See also**

[Query#getResultList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

update statement returns the result is Integer

```
update ProgramAccess p set p.isDeleted = 1 where p.id in (:progId)
```